# How to restrict other websites from accessing by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

Recently I have encounter a strange issue , my website `www.xyz.com` is being pointed by some one on the web domain let suppose `www.abc.com`.

Though the whole website is on `www.xyz.com` but the other domain display every single content and directory path structure by their domain...e.g. the real path is `www.xyz.com/somepage/id/etc`  can be work by www.abc.com/somepage/id/etc with same directory paths....

This other website is just redirecting everything to my website and I want to stop this domain to use my directory structure. This `www.abc.com` is also being crawled by  Google crawler and added its link in Google search engine.

This is a very new issue to me I have one solution to restrict every single request and check if its from my own website or not.

Second solution is to restrict them through `htaccess` but I don't find perfect solution using `htaccess`. 
I saw on the web it stop all the referrer, but doing that I am afraid if it will stop users coming from other website to my website ...I just need to restrict other domains to use my whole website as theirs using redirection...i have taken this issue on go daddy and they said they also don't know why the other website is pointing to my ip address ... so clueless I need expert advice to secure my website from future issues like this ...kindly advice...

My htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and i am using YII...

Comment: Just look at google for "apache rewrite referrer" and how to evaluate it inside apaches rewriting module. There are millions of examples for this on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.xyz\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Philip i have tried this but it has even stop my own domain , please check my question again i have edit and posted my .htaccess file...i am using your code below the RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: Try that now with the tweak I just made; It works on my testing server.

Comment: THANKSSSSS man... it worked however the sub domains and google reference like http://xyz.net/ are not working , i have two three subdomains like secure.xyz.net , bugtrack.xyz.net...it only works with www.xyz.net really i need your advice for this as well??

Comment: I have tweaked the example with an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} abc\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} abc\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !xyz\.(com|net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution , your solution though is much better but i have given the other answer a green signal... but i will give you vote up..once again thanks it works all way around.

Comment: I always forget my escapes.